# make variable from string php

Tags: php, variables

I have the code snippet below

```
    foreach ($response as $sms) {

        $receiver = "(".$sms['from'].",\"".$sms['body']."\",".$sms['timestamp'].")";                     
        $res .=$receiver.",";
    }
    $res = substr($res, 0, -1);
```

How can I make `$sms['from']` - variable and use it outside this code?

Thanks

Comment: Not possible, you should define a new array and save `$sms['from']` in it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array out side of the loop and from the loop push each of the `$sms['from']` to that array. Once the loop is completed it will have all the items.

```
$sms_from = [];  

foreach ($response as $sms) {
    $sms_from[] = $sms['from'];
    $receiver = "
     (".$sms['from'].",\"".$sms['body']."\",".$sms['timestamp'].")";                     
    $res .=$receiver.",";
}
$res = substr($res, 0, -1);

var_dump($sms_from);// contains all the $sms['from']
```

Comment: got a typo in line 3: `$mss` (and a missing `;`)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try

Comment: It gives answer: array(0) { }.  Date is in the table @Shobi P P

Comment: or answer: array(2) { [0]=> NULL [1]=> NULL }